# Sum algebra solving for coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Is the following equation solvable for $k$?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_ie^{kx_i}}{1+e^{kx_i}} = 0$$

Comment: Is there any information about $x_i$?

Comment: @Andrei $x_i$ is a real number $\in [-1, 1]$.

Comment: If all $x_i>0$ then $k=-\infty$. If all $x_i<0$ than $k=\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my previous comment, if all $x_i>0$ then $k=-\infty$ and if all $x_i<0$ than $k=\infty$. I can prove that the equation is solvable, without giving an explicit solution in the rest of the cases.

We can write each term as
$$\frac{x_i e^{k x_i}}{1+e^{k x_i}}=\frac{d}{dk}\ln(1+e^{k x_i})$$
Gathering all terms we get:
$$\frac{d}{dk}\sum_{i=1}^N \ln(1+e^{k x_i})=\frac{d}{dk}\ln(\prod_{i=1}^N (1+e^{k x_i}))$$
If there are both positive and negative $x_i$, the product at $\pm\infty$ is $+\infty$. The function $f(k)=\ln(\prod_{i=1}^N (1+e^{k x_i}))$ is continuous, it is bounded on the lower part by 0 (the product is at least 1, since all exponentials are >0), so it has at least one minimum between $(-\infty,+\infty)$, so there is a point where the derivative is 0.